# Spring JPA returning infinite recursion from JpaRepository

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a controller class like so

```
@Controller
public class ExerciseController {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ExerciseController.class);

    private final ExerciseRepository exerciseRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ExerciseController(ExerciseRepository exerciseRepository) {
        this.exerciseRepository = exerciseRepository;
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/exercises")
    public ResponseEntity<Exercise> createExercise(@RequestBody Exercise exercise) {
        Exercise savedExercise = exerciseRepository.save(exercise);
        return new ResponseEntity<Exercise>(savedExercise,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/exercises/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Exercise> getExerciseById(@PathVariable int id) {
        Exercise exercise = exerciseRepository.getOne(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Exercise>(exercise, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The repository linked to this controller is a simple JpaRepository like so

```
package com.company.app.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.company.app.model.Exercise;

@Repository
public interface ExerciseRepository extends JpaRepository<Exercise, Integer> {
    Exercise findById(int id);
}
```

When I try to hit the endpoint associated with `/exercises/{id}` I get infinite recursion. The `Exercise` model is set up like so

```
package com.company.app.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumns;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name="exercise")
@Data
public class Exercise {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    
    @MapsId("chapterId")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="chapterId", referencedColumnName="id"),
    })
    @ManyToOne
    private Chapter chapter;

    private String exercise;

    private String answer;

    private String question;

    private String a;
    
    private String b;

    private String c;
}
```

I'd like to know why this is returning infinite recursion? The error that I am receiving is

```
2021-04-02 19:30:28.120 ERROR 110200 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.e.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView : Cannot render error page for request [/exercises/1] and exception [Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.company.app.model.Account["user"]->
```

Chapter implementation

```
package com.company.app.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumns;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name="chapter")
@Data
public class Chapter {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    
    private String title;
    
    @MapsId("bookId")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="bookId", referencedColumnName="id"),
    })
    @ManyToOne
    private Book book;

}
```

Comment: Share your Chapter implementation.

Comment: @Md.KawserHabib I added it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of `@Data` annotations which create equals/hashCode/toString implementations for all fields by default, so you have an infinite loop between `Exercise` and `Chapter` in these methods.

I would recommend you exclude these fields by adding `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` and `@ToString.Exclude` on `chapter` and `exercise` fields.

Comment: like this 
```
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private String exercise;
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me unfortunately. However, what did make a difference was commenting out the chapter_id field in the Exercise class. I replaced it with `private int chapterId` and it worked. I do need to figure out how to place the constraint on the field though to maintain referential integrity.